# How to generate a users choice table

Tags: php

I am attempting to create a table that consists of 2 forms where the first form gets info from the second. so i have table1 and table 2. I want to make it to be users choice . a user picks the number of rows and columns(I went up to 7 rows and columns in dropbox) and color from a drop down box and whatever they pick it generates. My problem is when I select something instead of showing me a table row and columns with the colors its showing me 1111 can anyone suggest something? Maybe my logic is wrong please help.

```
 <?php
  $color=    substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET,'color',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,10);
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Table">
<meta name="description" content="table Creator">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <style>
          tr:nth-child(even)        { 
            background-color:#000000; 
            color:#000000; 
            <?php
            echo $color
            ?>;
        }
       table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid #000000; ;
        padding: 10px;
       }
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>

    <title>table</title>


  </head>

 <body>
  <header>
        <h1> Projects</h1>
    </header>


    <nav>

  </nav>

  <section>

  <h2> Table Creator</h2>



 <?php
 $rows= substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET,'rows',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,3);
  $cols= substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET,'cols',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,3);


  echo "<Table>";


for ($x=1; $x<=$rows; $x++)
 {

  echo "<tr>";
  for ($y=1; $y<=$cols; $y++)

echo  "<td>$rows $x $cols $y</td>";
 }

{
 echo "<tr>";
}

echo "</Table>";




  ?>


</section>

<footer>

 </footer>

  <p></p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: maybe it's because you're printing $rows $x $cols $y

Comment: ok but im confused on how to get it to actually say what i need. like if a user picks 1row 2columns and red from the dropdown menu what should be my logic for what they pick

Comment: can you past the html code of the generated page